# Why can't we update a view which has DISTINCT Clause in its definition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am not getting the logic behind the fact that a view can't be updated if it has DISTINCT Clause in its definition . Please guide with an example .

Comment: Because those are the rules that Oracle enforces.  What kind of example do you want?  It doesn't work and it is well documented.  Period.

Comment: an example to illustrate the reason behind this enforcement

Comment: Maybe ask Oracle ;)

Comment: @radha The reason is simple: if you were a DBMS, which row in base table will you update if you have `distinct`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why is this question closed? It seems pretty clear to me, he wants to know the logic behind the rules. Unless it's off-topic, in which case shouldn't it be migrated to softwareengineering or dba?

Comment: @Charlieface . . . "Please give an example of why Oracle implemented a particular restriction" does not seem like a clear question to me.  There might be a reasonable answer to why the restriction is in place, but definitely not to an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value1, value2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2 FROM DUAL;
```

and the view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW view_name ( value1, value2 ) AS
SELECT DISTINCT value1, value2 FROM table_name;
```

and you try to do:

```sql
UPDATE view_name
SET value2 = 2
WHERE ( value1, value2 ) IN ( (1, 1) );
```

Which row should be updated?

- Should it be the first row? or the second row? Either could be used as the `DISTINCT` value. In which case there would still be a `DISTINCT` row that has the `1, 1` pairing and it would appear that the update had done nothing.
- Both the first and second row? So that afterwards there would be no `1, 1` pairing?

The expected behaviour is ambiguous as either result could be a valid solution.

Oracle removes the potential ambiguity by disallowing updates on aggregated/distinct views.

From the [Oracle `UPDATE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm#sthref10009):

> - If you specify view, then the database updates the base table of the view. You cannot update a view except with `INSTEAD OF` triggers if the defining query of the view contains one of the following constructs:
>
>   - A set operator
>   - A `DISTINCT` operator
>   - An aggregate or analytic function
>   - A `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, `MODEL`, `CONNECT BY`, or `START WITH` clause
>   - ...

Comment: There's no first row in SQL and especially in heap organized table - just not to be provoking "I want to update the first row in my table" questions and use the SQL data as a set, not row-wise

Comment: The ordering of a `SELECT` clause is non-deterministic but from an English language point-of-view there is a concept of the "first row that was inserted" and we can use that to distinguish between the rows; otherwise we are getting into needless pedantry.